# Can't start VM in Virtual Box after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 13.10, virtualbox

I just upgraded to `13.10` and now, Virtual Box wouldn't let me start my virtual machine anymore. It tells me to execute `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` but If I do, I get the following:

```
# /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                                                                                       [ OK ] 
 * Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules                                                                                                                                 Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File:  does not exist.
                                                                                                                                                                            [ OK ]
 * Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS                                                                                                                     Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.11.0-14-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.24/build/make.log for more information.

 * Failed, trying without DKMS
 * Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                                                                                           
 * Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong
root@regDesktopHome:/lib/modules/3.11.0-14-generic/build/include/linux#
```

and in the log file I see:

```
    echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
    echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
```

How can I get this fixed? Please advise!

Comment: Have you installed dkms and the headers for the running kernel?

Comment: @Terry Wang not explicitly but they should have gotten upgraded as well I'd expect..trying dkms tells me `dkms is already the newest version.` - so it got upgraded accordingly, hey? But I'm now installing `virtualbox-dkms` - see if that helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing `virtualbox-dkms` and running `/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` again resolved the issue!